# Quotient of Ring of Functions on a Field by a Maximal Ideal is Algebraically Closed Implies Field is Algebraically Closed

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I'm having trouble with this one.

Let $K$ be a field, $X$ a non-empty set, and $\mathcal{F}(X;K)$ the ring of functions from X on K. If $\mathfrak{m}$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathcal{F}(X;K)$ such that $\mathcal{F}(X;K)/ \mathfrak{m}$ is an algebraically closed field, then $K$ is algebraically closed too.

I don't know where to start. Any hints?

Comment: Embed $K$ in $\mathcal{F}(X;K)$ as the constant functions.  If you have a polynomial over $K$ which has a root in $\mathcal{F}(X;K)/ \mathfrak{m}$, what does that mean concretely in terms of elements of $\mathcal{F}(X;K)$?

Comment: It means that this polynomial, say $f \in K[x]$, evaluated at this root, say $\alpha \in \mathcal{F}(X;K)/\mathfrak{m}$, is in $\mathfrak{m}$, right? And then what?

Comment: OK, and what can elements of $\mathfrak{m}$ possibly look like?  Which elements of $\mathcal{F}(X;K)$ can be in a maximal ideal?

Comment: Non invertible elements, that is, functions $f: X \to K$ such that there is $x_0 \in X$ with $ f(x_0)=0$. I guess that finishes it, don't it?